# Windows Pointer Speed 1/11 Left/Right Difference

Tags: windows, mouse

I found this old post, where someone embedded a really long guide about setting mouse sensitivity for CS.
https://www.overclock.net/threads/cs-s-mouse-optimization-guide.173255/

Antigen states that if you lower the pointer setting in windows below 6/11, you would have two different DPI settings for moving left and right. I quote:

"On the other hand, if you reduce the pointer speed setting, even by one notch, you get two different mouse sensitivities and your cursor will move, slowly to the right, and faster to the left."

All of this dates back to the Windows XP Era. I wonder if this is still relevant, and hope someone has an idea what's going on with the settings. Antigen unfortunately didn't explain why lowering the pointer speed results in such weird behaviour.

I tried testing it with https://www.mouse-sensitivity.com/dpianalyzer/, but couldn't observe a difference in going left or right. I tested it once with the max DPI setting on my mouse and once with a fairly low setting. Unfortunately going for high DPI results in a lot of deviation because i dont have an apparition to hold the mouse in parallel to the ruler (cm on paper). With the low setting it also seemed like both directions are equal.
Is this a myth that got debunked or a "bug" that was fixed in later versions of Windows?
I understand that i don't get any latency benefit by dropping windows pointer speed and bumbing dpi on mouse, i just wanted to max out the dpi on the mouse for kicks.

Comment: Hi Lange Zeit, do you know if this is Windows behaviour that is just more clearly visible in CS, or if it has to do with the compatibility between the two, and intrinsic to CS? I wonder if this question could receive better answers on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: to be honest i don't know if it's even true. in the forum this opinion was shared extensively and it became a common thing for cs players to think that anything besides 6/11 setting in the middle is bad. thank you for the hint i will repost the question on SuperUser.